# Counting consecutive days

Tags: bug, ios-app

I'm not 100% sure whether this is a bug with the iPhone app or at the server end, but it seems to me that the site is not accurately counting consecutive days if you happen to be away from a desktop computer and use the iPhone app instead to visit the site on a particular day.

This situation seems to reset the count. I've been 'testing' this theory now for a while across multiple communities.

It would be appreciated if this could be looked into.

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 9.3.5 (Build 13G36)

Comment: Are you actually accessing individual questions? Accessing the feed does *not* count towards your progress.

Comment: No, not always - but then I don't always do that from a desktop computer either, and it still seems to be counted.

Comment: @Monomeeth but when you use the app the feed (assuming by Feed we are talking about the first screen which appears when you boot the app from start) is taking content from multiple sites. the counting of consecutive days is site dependent ie. if your on for 20 consecutive days on Super User via desktop but visit Tor after having not been there for a week you'll see that Tor doesn't have you as having 20 consecutive days from Super User, as you can see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XMeiz.png) and [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/quKPI.png)

Comment: Agreed. I am saying that I have tested this by visiting 12 sites daily. During the test I did this from a work desktop computer from Mon-Thu, on Friday from a home desktop computer and on Sunday ONLY from an iPhone. However, for one site I still checked it from a home desktop computer on Sunday. Back to Monday, one site shows an unbroken count for consecutive days, the other 11 have started again. I had a reminder on my phone to refresh all sites each day at 4am and 11pm UTC time.

Comment: I do have the Stack Exchange app running 24/7 on my iPhone, would that be causing an issue? Do I need to quit it and relaunch it each day?

Comment: But what exactly are you doing when you visit it from the app? As I said, simply looking at the feed *intentionally does not count* towards progress. And there are probably some other things that do not qualify within the app itself. Similarly, only logging in or visiting the homepage on the desktop version will not count towards your progress either. To know whether or not there's a problem, we need to know exactly what you're trying to do that's not being counted.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the behaviour should be consistent. By that I mean that what I'm doing from the App is exactly the same thing I'm doing when using a desktop computer, so it should either count or not count on both platforms, rather than count on one and not on the other. In summary, I added all my test sites to the main Stack Exchange menu. My testing involved loading up a site on the desktop computer and then one by one selecting other sites from the main Stack Exchange dropdown menu. When using the app I do the same thing - select each site one by one from my sites list.